# Nash Equilibrium Multi Objective Genetic Algorithm Java

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am beginning work on a Masters thesis regarding comparison of Nash equilibrium based MOGA solutions vs ones that output Pareto-Optimal curves,

I was just wondering if anyone has any experience with a good example of an existing algorithm which outputs the Nash equilibrium, or Pareto Curves, which I can work with.

If not a framework which seems good for my purposes if it turns out I need to build these myself(I can of course swap languages but I work in Java but have seen frameworks such as JGAP and JCLEC) There are quite a few frameworks to choose from so some insight from someone with experience would be great!

please be clear I don't want anyone to do my research for me, I have been looking around a lot but am new to this area and could use a bit of direction as I know not all algorithms and frameworks are made equal.

-Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about nash equilibrium in particular. However, for finding pareto fronts using evolutionary algorithms, the most complete framework, by far, is [jMetal](http://jmetal.sourceforge.net/). It is written in Java and implements most state-of-the-art algorithms. Morever, it implements a large number of classic problems (ZDT/DTLZ suites), so you have a lot of examples on how to formulate your problem.

The MOGA algorithm is quite old and is outperformed by most recent algorithms. I would suggest trying the good-old NSGA2/SPEA2 algorithms, as well as the newer MOCELL, ABYSS and MOEA/D and see which one works better in your case.

Comment: As I get closer to completing my thesis this advice(both jmetal as well as NSGAII) has run quite true and useful, thank you!!!